# Как посчитать длину отрезка между двумя концами вектора и надрезом плоскостью?

Tags: геометрия

У меня есть бедро треугольника(координаты x,y,z точки A и точки B) которое рассекается плоскостью(задана точкой лежащей на плоскости и ее нормалью).
Как просчитать дистанцию точки А к надрезу плоскостью на отрезке AB, и так же от B к надрезу?

Comment: Какое отношение метки split и geometry относятся к вашему вопросу?

Comment: тоесть по вашому мой вопрос к геометрии никак не относится?)

Comment: Для геометрии есть метка "геометрия". Но в целом, вопросы чисто по геометрии без связи с программированием на грани оффтопика на данном сайте. Ну и по поводу split все еще не понятно - зачем как попало расставлять метки.

Comment: тоесть триангуляция мэшей не имеет связи с программированием?)

Comment: Где в вашем вопросе что-то про триангуляцию мешей? P.S. ну и я и написал, что на грани оффтопика, потому что действительно вопрос может быть связан с программированием, но из самого вопроса это может быть не очевидно.

Comment: мой вопрос напрямую с этим связан, сплит делит стл модель на 2 части и треугольники находящиеся на месте пересечения с сплитом(расколом) делятся на 3 новых треугольника.

Comment: Замечательно. Я поправил метки, в дальнейшем будьте аккуратнее с ними, пожалуйста. Метку split лучше не использовать, потому что она может означать вообще все что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

1. Перевести отрезок в параметризованное уравнение прямой.
2. Перевести плоскость в канонический вид.
3. Подставить `x`, `y`, `z` из 1. в 2., найти значение параметра и координаты точки пересечения.
4. Найти расстояние от `А` до точки пересечения.
5. Найти расстояние от `B` до точки пересечения.

---

*P.S. "надрез" - ??*

Comment: надрез - место рассечения плоскостью

Comment: @Michael Звучит очень драматично. На человеческом языке это называется - точка пересечения прямой и плоскости.

Comment: фактически модель рассекается плоскостью на 2 части, а не просто пересекается

Comment: @Michael Меня совершенно не интересует Ваша "модель". Тем более что в вопросе этого слова вообще нет.

Comment: да, есть слово Бедро, которое !рассекается! плоскостью

Comment: @Michael Что "да"? Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне не совсем помог, что такое канонический вид плоскости, как правильно переводить отрезок и тд?
Не все люди знают геометрию отлично, если бы это было так, вопрос бы я не задавал

Comment: @Michael Здесь не детский сад. Что такое канонический вид уравнения плоскости ищется за пять секунд.

Comment: А что такое бедро треугольника?