# Поиск координат точки пересечения отрезка с плоскостью

Tags: геометрия

Как найти точку пересечения отрезка (заданного точками Axyz и Bxyz) плоскостью(заданную точкой лежащей на плоскости и нормалью)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358597

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1358626/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Michael, ну вы что-то сегодня какие-то сходные вопросы задаете, которые присутствуют в учебниках геометрии (ну или аналитической геометрии)

алгоритм

1. получить уравнение прямой по 2 точкам

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F#%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5

https://mnogoformul.ru/uravnenie-pryamoj-po-dvum-tochkam

2. проверить, является ли прямая параллельной плоскости или лежит на плоскости
3. найти точку пересечения прямой с плоскостью

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

http://www.cleverstudents.ru/line_and_plane/intersection_point_of_line_and_plane.html

https://matworld.ru/analytic-geometry/tochka-peresechenija-prjamoj-i-ploskosti.php

http://mathprofi.ru/zadachi_s_pryamoi_i_ploskostju.html

и т.д.

4. определить, находится ли точка внутри отрезка (лежит ли внутри координат p1..p2)

вот такая система должна выполняться:

```
min(x1, x2) <= x0 <= max(x1, x2) 
min(y1, y2) <= y0 <= max(y1, y2) 
min(z1, z2) <= z0 <= max(z1, z2)
```

Comment: Они не хотят читать учебники, а хотят, чтобы им дали формулы. А лучше - код.

Comment: понятное желание :) но иногда формулы такие большие, что код просто лень писать в качестве ответа

Comment: Понятное - но плохое.

Comment: Где была просьба написать код?

Answer (score 0):

```
AB = B - A
d = Base.dot.N
t = (d -  A.dot.N) / (AB.dot.N)
```

Если `AB.dot.N==0`, то отрезок параллелен плоскости.

Если t в пределах 0...1, то пересечение есть, координаты его `A + t * AB`